# Why are the images distorted in iOS build?

Tags: unity, xcode

I'm working on a match three game. But, when I generate iOS build, the images are distorted and completely unrecognizable.
However, the issue happens only on some systems. I tried it on an iMac running El Capitan and Xcode 7.2, a Mac mini running Mavericks and Xcode 6.1. On these systems, the images were distorted.
I tried on another Mac mini running Mavericks and Xcode 6.1 and there was no distortion.

This is how undistorted images look:
[image]

And this is how the distorted images look:
[image]

I'm clueless as to why this happens. Please provide some help. Thanks

Comment: I think only your green pumpkin like image is distorted, right?

Comment: No, it is randomly affecting all type of images

Comment: So then where your sparkling effect takes place?

Comment: If you are referring to the purple fruit in third row, fourth column, that is a power up. Also, please note the screenshots are not of the same screen. They are randomly generated.

Comment: I know boy, I was just asking if anything specific is happened or the bug is random

Comment: Well, there are two common reasons for that.. First is your shader, may be the shader you are using for images is not fully supported and second thing may be your image settings is not properly configured (which is rare)

Comment: I'm using default sprite, so shader can't be the problem. Import settings are also default....also, this happens on some systems, not all. So far generated proper build on two systems, faced this issue on two others. No changes made to anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35732/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-sansolo).

Comment: Try to set filter mode to point in sprite import settings

Comment: Tried, without any success. Also, settings shouldn't matter as it works fine from some systems.

Comment: If you are saying that building from some systems has no issue on deployment, then it is really weird ...

Comment: May be some one has experience this particular issue may answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

A very old question, but the issue was resolved. The issue was with the iMac used to generate this build. Used a different mac and the build was ok.